# Use inline(ARRAY<STRUCT[,STRUCT]>) in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Has someone been able to use that function before, I have tried pretty much every combination in order to see if it works.

This is the Array of Struct I am trying to use with inline

```
[{"position":1,"price":124.0,"card_pos":"External","clicked":0},
 {"position":2,"price":94.78,"card_pos":"Cbox","clicked":0},
 {"position":3,"price":94.77,"card_pos":"External","clicked":0}]
```

This works nicely:

```sql
select iq.*, iq.card.position as position, 
iq.card.price as price,iq.card.card_pos as card_pos, 
iq.card.clicked as clicked 
from
(
  select *
  from 
  hsim.im_metasearch
  LATERAL VIEW explode(cards) card as card
) iq
```

It's kind of annoying that I can's make the inline function work.
The documentation on the Hive Wiki is very vague on how this function should be used properly.

We have Hive 0.10(CDH4.6), the inline function is definitely part of our distribution.

If someone as concrete example of how to use it please let me know

I have tried a couple of different syntax

```sql
select *
from 
hsim.im_metasearch
Lateral view inline(cards) as(position,price,card_pos,clicked)

select *
from 
hsim.im_metasearch
Lateral view inline(cards) card as (position,price,card_pos,clicked)
```

I've also tried to put it in the select without success
Thank you

Comment: definitely hive complains about the `as` part and naming the columns despite that being shown in the DDL. It seems that syntax only works if you are doing a select solely of `inline` such as `select inline(cards) as (pos,pri,cps,clk) from hsim.im_metasearch;`

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how I have (successfully) used `inline`.  Suppose we have a dataset such as

```
id    |    num
---------------
1          2.0
1          4.0
2          5.0
1          7.0
1          8.0
2          8.0
1          3.0
1          5.0
1          6.0
3          7.0
```

if you perform the query

```
select histogram_numeric(num, 3)
from table
```

you will get a histogram grouped into 3 bins represented as an array of structs.

```
[{'x':2.5, 'y:2.0'}, {'x':5.0, 'y':4.0}, {'x':7.5, 'y':4.0}]
```

Most people would want to view this in some sort of table form, hence the `inline` function. So we could do

```
select inline(histogram_numeric(num, 3))
from table
```

This gives

```
x    |    y
-------------
2.5      2.0
5.0      4.0
7.5      4.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Were you ever able to use the inline statement in the LATERAL VIEW statement. Your post is great does not fix my problem. My question would be, could you have other fields appended in front of x and y. The Hive doc seems to say you can't. I might be wrong.

Comment: For my case, the array of struct is with each line/record. The goal is to each Struct from the array would be exploded and than put inline after all the field already in the table. From your example, it looks like inline can only be used on it's own and can't have other fields in front of it.

Comment: If you could edit your question and describe what the data looks like that you are querying from and what you want it to look like afterwards  I could possibly help.  It is difficult to tell exactly what you are trying to achieve when there are just queries in your question.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
select * 
from table1 t
   lateral view inline(array_of_structs) a
;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query:**

```
select * from ( select ARRAY(named_struct('a1', 1, 'a2', 2)) as kk  from dim_one_row ) x lateral view  inline(kk)  t as ff, ff2;
```

**Result:**

```
[{"a1":1,"a2":2}]       1       2
```